# Weird java.net.SocketException Permission Denied connect error when running Groovy in Intellij IDEA

Tags: sockets, url, groovy, intellij-idea

When running a ***VERY*** simple URL grab script from within IntelliJ IDEA, I get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

but when I run it from the Groovy Console, it works just fine.

Here is the full script:

```
def data = new URL("http://wisc.edu").getText()
```

and here is the full console output from IntelliJ:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\java" "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\lib\tools.jar" "-Dgroovy.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2" "-Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\conf\groovy-starter.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 110.492\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\groovy-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 110.492\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --conf "C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\conf\groovy-starter.conf" --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain --classpath "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\IdeaProjects\test\out\production\test;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\ant-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\ant-antlr-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\ant-junit-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\asm-3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\asm-analysis-3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\asm-commons-3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\asm-tree-3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\asm-util-3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\balloontip-20090102.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-anim-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-awt-util-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-bridge-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-codec-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-css-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-dom-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-ext-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-extension-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-gui-util-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-gvt-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-parser-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-script-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-svggen-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-swing-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-transcoder-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-util-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\batik-xml-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\bsf-2.4.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\cssbuilder-0.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\cssparser-0.9.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\easyb-0.9.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\extra166y-1.7.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\flamingo-4.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\flamingobuilder-0.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\forms-1.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\gant-1.9.6_groovy-1.8.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\gfxbuilder-core-0.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\gfxbuilder-svg-0.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\gfxbuilder-swingx-0.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\gmock-0.8.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\gpars-0.12.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\groovy-1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\groovypp-0.9.0_1.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\groovyserv-0.9.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\ivy-2.2.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jacob-1.14.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jansi-1.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jcsp-1.1-rc5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jide-oss-2.9.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jidebuilder-4.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jna-3.2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jsilhouette-geom-0.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jsp-api-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\jsr166y-1.7.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\l2fprod-common-all-6.9.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\macwidgets-0.9.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\macwidgetsbuilder-0.4.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\maven-ant-tasks-2.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\multiplegradientpaint-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\multiverse-beta-0.7-RC-1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\netty-3.1.5.GA.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-ie-6-tlb-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-office-2K3-tlb-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-sapi-tlb-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-scripting-tlb-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-wbem-tlb-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\scriptom-wsh-tlb-1.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\spock-core-0.6-groovy-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\swing-worker-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\swingx-beaninfo-1.6.2-2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\swingx-core-1.6.2-2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\swingxbuilder-0.1.8.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\swingxtrasbuilder-0.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\timingframework-1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\trident-6.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\tridentbuilder-0.5.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\xstream-1.4.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.2\lib\xswingx-0.2.jar" --encoding=UTF-8 C:\Users\[REDACTED]\IdeaProjects\test\test.groovy
Caught: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at test.run(test.groovy:9)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have absolutely *no* idea what is causing the problem, but my guess is that it's something IDEA is doing when it runs the groovy code that keeps it from being able to access the network.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696) in JDK 1.7 related to IPv6.

Adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in **VM Options** should fix the problem.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990663/) related question on this site.

Comment: If that does not fix the problem, COMPLETELY uninstall 1.7 and install 1.6.  I still had this problem because version 7 java was being used from \Windows\System32 since my user path was after it

Comment: fyi from the Ticket; 
1.WORK AROUND   Run with -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
                                   
;     2. EVALUATION 2011-11-09  
This does not appear to be a JDK bug, rather it's just the Windows firewall recognizing and blocking the ftp protocol. The only difference between JDK7 and older releases is that the JDK is using IPv6 sockets when IPv6 is enabled and so IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses are used. it may be that Windows or the firewall is not configured to allow IPv6 sockets.

Comment: I observed the same behavior when a) running a mock server in SoapUI with bundled Java 12 b) trying to talk to that server from a backend tomcat 9 running on Java 8! I had to supply the above parameter to both SoapUI VM options and to tomcat 9 VM options.. hm...

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's an old and accepted answer, I faced same issue with java 1.8 and IntelliJ Idea21,  I found it difficult to find the right VM Option file to be updated the -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in VM Options

The correct location of the file for my idea installation is,

**IDE_HOME\bin<product>[bits][.exe].vmoptions** file  (C:\ideaIC-2021.3.3.win\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions)

Just editing and adding VM Option through Help -> Edit Custom VM Options didn't help

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties