# Could not connect to SMTP host error in my local only

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am getting this error while trying to send mail through java mail. It used to work for me, but recently I switched to jdk7 and glassfish 3.1.2. I tried to switch it back to jdk6 also but it's not working anymore, here is the error I'm getting:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.illumina.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
                java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Telnet and ping to this server is fine. Its working from other systems. Only my local setup is throwing this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360913/weird-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-error-when-running-groo

Comment: Sounds like a firewall related issue, are you using linux? try as root