# Cause of "Software caused connection abort: recv  failed"

Tags: java, sockets

I found a client/server code and I am getting this error:

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv  failed

Server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server{

//port number should be more than 1024

public static final int PORT = 1025;

public static void main( String args[]) throws IOException
{
 ServerSocket sersock = null;
 Socket sock = null;
 System.out.println(" Wait !! ");

 try
 {
  //  Initialising the ServerSocket
  sersock =  new ServerSocket(PORT);

  // Gives the Server Details Machine name, Port number

  System.out.println("Server Started  :"+sersock);

  try
  {

   // makes a socket connection to particular client after 
   // which two way communication take place

   sock = sersock.accept();

   System.out.println("Client Connected  :"+ sock);

   // Receive message from client i.e Request from client

   BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
   // Send message to the client i.e Response

   PrintStream ios = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
   ios.println("Hello from server");
   ios.close();

   // Close the Socket connection 

    sock.close();

    }
    catch(SocketException se)
    {
    System.out.println("Server Socket problem  "+se.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println("Couldn't start " 
                  + e.getMessage()) ;     
    }               

 // Usage of some methods in Socket class

  System.out.println(" Connection from :  " + 
  sock.getInetAddress());

 }finally{} // main 

}
}// Server class
```

Client code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class client
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 Socket sock=null;
 DataInputStream dis=null;
 PrintStream ps=null;
 System.out.println(" Trying to connect");

 try 
 {
 // to get the ip address of the  server by the name

 InetAddress ip =InetAddress.getByName
 ("localhost");

 // Connecting to the port 1025 declared in the Serverclass
 // Creates a socket with the server bind to it.

  sock= new Socket(ip,1025);
  ps= new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
  ps.println(" Hi from client");
  BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
  System.out.println(is.readLine());

 }
 catch(SocketException e)
 {
  System.out.println("SocketException " + e);
 }
 catch(IOException e)
 {
  System.out.println("IOException " + e);
 }

  // Finally closing the socket from the client side

 finally
 {
 try
  {
   sock.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ie)
  {
   System.out.println(" Close Error   :" + 
   ie.getMessage());
  }               
 }  // finally 

} // main 
}   // Class Client
```

The Server code gives the following output:

```
C:\WorkStation\Testcserver\src>java Server
 Wait !!
Server Started  :ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=1025]
Client Connected  :Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=56143,localport=1025]
 Connection from :  /127.0.0.1

C:\WorkStation\Testcserver\src>
```

The client code gives the following output:

```
C:\WorkStation\testClient\src>java client
 Trying to connect
SocketException java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv
 failed
```

```
    C:\WorkStation\testClient\src>java client
 Trying to connect
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
        at client.main(client.java:30)
```

Comment: Change your client code to print the full stack trace of the exception, not just the exception message.

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long.

Here's the stack trace:
EDIT: Uh, the <pre> output </pre> doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The server just exits after the client connects, is that the problem?

Comment: Are you running under Windows?  I have seen this error occur when the Windows firewall interferes with network communication.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990663/java-7-prevents-ftp-transfers-on-windows-vista-and-7-if-firewall-is-on-any-idea

Comment: @Emil Styrke: Yes and no. It is supposed to say Hi from client on the server output and Hi from server on the client output. when I have 2 console windows open and run the client and server code, I get the error I posted above (the stack trace one).

Comment: @prunge:
I tried disabling the firewall, didn't work.

The weird thing is, It worked at first.. but now it doesn't : /

Comment: @user1021085: But the server isn't waiting for any data from the client, and when the server exits the connection will be closed.  I think you have a race condition between the server exiting and the client receiving its data.

Comment: @Emil Styrke:
How can I make it wait for data?

By the way, I added System.out.println(ins.readLine()); to the server code and changed part of the client code to   BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
  System.out.println(is.readLine());. How embaressing..

Comment: @user1021085: You're not reading anything from the client in the server.  If you add a `ins.readLine()` to the server code the server will wait for data from the client before proceeding.

Comment: @Emil Styke:
Yes, they say hi to eachother now.
But how would I go about making a chat?
How can I make it keep waiting for input from the server/the client?

Comment: I think that is out of scope for this comment field, but basically you have to put a loop around the readLine/println calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server isn't waiting for any data from the client, and when the server exits the connection will be closed.

Add a `ins.readLine()` to the server code like this:

```
// Receive message from client i.e Request from client

BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(ins.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to Client authentication. 
It happened to me when I was trying to access SOAP API from Java code without setting keystore/keystorePassword and from the stacktrace there is no way we can figure out that there's a problem with Authentication.

After I added following lines before making call to SOAP API and it worked as expected.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "Your Cert Type");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "Your cert path");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "Password");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues related to Firewall. Please turn off Firewall or else, connect your internet to wifi/personal wifi. These solution worked for me.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).