# netbeans php remote server upload files

Tags: php, netbeans, ftp

I'm a student, new to netBean php remote server. I was trying to upload php files to remote server through netbeans (on run). I'm sure everything in run configuration, ftp information is correct, I have rights to upload file to that folder.

And this error occur: 
Message prompt:

`"Cannot logout from server *name. Reason 250 OK. Current directory: *dir name"`

Logs:

```
Log in output window:
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 17 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 04:13. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
USER a4514022
331 User a4514022 OK. Password required
PASS ******
230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230-362 files used (3%) - authorized: 10000 files
230 2476 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 1536000 Kb
TYPE I
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
CWD /public_html
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
CWD /public_html
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
```

## Summary

Failed:
file      test.php     Cannot upload file test.php (unknown reason).
Runtime: 408 ms, transfered: 0 file(s), 0 KB

I don't get what happen. How to fix it?
I use netbean 6.9.1, windows 7 and java ver 7 (build 1.7.0_05) platform 1.7 Those numbers, I don't know which one is the version. I just put all those there. It seems I'm the rare one get this problem...

Comment: What java and windows version are you using?
There are some known problems in regards to the newest java version in combination with windows vista/windows 7  and ftp remote servers.

Comment: it's windows 7 and java ver 7 (build 1.7.0_05) platform 1.7
Those numbers, I don't know which one is the version you're asking. I just put all those there. It seems I'm the rare one get this problem...

Comment: I had similar problems...although a different errormessage a while ago.
Have you tried disabling stateful FTP already? (that helped me).
To do this you need to put the following into commandline:
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable

More details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990663/java-7-prevents-ftp-transfers-on-windows-vista-and-7-if-firewall-is-on-any-idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Know you asked this and probably your problem has solved
but I write this for the another ones;
first check the Proxy. 
Tools>Option>Proxy Settings
and then set on the "no proxy" .
It will probably be solved.

Comment: Wow bro, It's been so long, I even quit netbeans and java, turn to xcode / ios / objective-c. I don't even know if your answer is correct anymore =]] Thanks anw.

Answer (score 0):

I had to select less secure option e.g. Encryption: Pure FTP option to get it working for GoDaddy setup.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes even later. I also had the error and ended up here in search.

My mistake was that I had the file I wanted to download in editing with another reader (outside Netbeans). In other words, the downloaded file could not be saved to local filesystem, because the opened file prevented that.